# Zoom image on hover

Tags: html, css

How can I make a image in my social feed to zoom when I hover over it.

similar to the instagram feed on the left in [this site](http://defiance-theme.tumblr.com).

I tried this in the hover css:

```
opacity: 0.5; 
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

but I couldn't get it to zoom.

Comment: `opacity` is not for zooming...

Comment: Well, for one thing...those aren't images.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this.

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 540px;
}

.item img {
  width: 500px;  
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://www.joshuacasper.com/contents/uploads/joshua-casper-samples-free.jpg" alt="pepsi" width="540" height="548">
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Might need an overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to :hover:

```
transform: scale(1.5);
```